# Ionic2 - ion-select element at RTL issue

Tags: angular, ionic2, multilingual, ionic2-select

I use angular2 and ionic 2.
My app support multy-languages.
When user click "change to hebrew" the following code is computed:

```
this.platform.setDir('rtl', true);
this.translate.use('he');
```

However, all the app move to rtl well.
But the ion-select element have not good look. You can see at the picture.
The radio-buttons are overflow the box, the labels and the title are align to left instead of right.
Any solution?

Here is a link to picture: 
http://jmp.sh/TOX6hOT1